# how to add configuration for log4net (or any other 3rd party library) in ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: json, configuration, log4net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was reading Scott Gu's blog on [ASP.NET 5.0 features](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) and one of the new feature mentioned in the blog is to use json file as configuration and elimination of Web.config file.

I have few questions around that feature.

Assume I have following log4net configuration which was previously added to Web.Config in previous version of ASP.NET

**Config file**

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\\TestProj\\TestLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

How would one add sections in config.json ?

How would one convert above xml and add it to config.json?

Does 3rd Party library ( In my example log4net ) or users of the library have to add some type of custom conversion api to support json based configuration, in order to take advantage of new configuration feature provided in ASP.NET 5.0?

Answer (score 12):

Recently I had the same problem with `log4net`. I managed to do it working as following:

Create `log4net.xml` file containing the configuration section for log4net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
...
</log4net>
```

You can put the file in the project root folder.

And in the `Startup.Startup()` method you can configure the `log4net` providing the xml as a configuration:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // ... 

    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath, "log4net.xml")));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yp, you may need to mark it as an output file so it is included in published app.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of log4net don't support Json projects, so the config needs to be in a separate xml file.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of where that file should be placed, what it should be named, what it should contain and how it can be added to the configuration system (in the Startup.cs file)?