# How to write log4net config into appsettings.json?

Tags: log4net, asp.net-core-2.0, log4net-configuration

I have implemented `log4net` into `.NET core 2.0`, to log into a text file. As log4net have a config file, which is having `XML configuration` in it. So, I have created a separate file `log4net.config` to set its configuration and it is working fine. But I want to set its configuration into `appsettings.json`. Is it possible to write the log4net configuration into `appsettings.json`.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IsLog" value="True" />
    <add key="MaxThreads" value="3" />
  </appSettings>
  <log4net debug="false">
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="./logs/logfile.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50GB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>   
  </log4net>
```

this is my XML configuration.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846338/how-to-add-configuration-for-log4net-or-any-other-3rd-party-library-in-asp-net) in which it is mentioned that `log4net don't support Json projects`. Is it possible to write its configuration into `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it is not the right way but, anyhow I managed to use my `log4net.config` in `appSettings.json`. I am putting my answer here so it can help someone if they don't want to use an extra config file for there project.

So what I have done is like by converting my **XML** into **JSON** and used the **JSON** as a string on my `appSettings.json` after that I use the following code to read the string.

> appSettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LoggerConfig": "Config string"
  }
}
```

> **Json** to **XML** Conversion using `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
 string xmlElement = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:LoggerConfig"];
 XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(xmlElement);
 XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, GenerateStreamFromString(doc.InnerXml));
```

This code is used to convert the **JSON** into **XML** but it will not provide the XML content as **Element** so, I used it as a stream.
For converting the string into a stream I used the following code.

```
        public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

and it works fine.

> Here I used to convert first my `XML to JSON` and again `JSON to XML` to
>   use it as a `log4net config`, but if anyone wants then use XML
>   directly as a string, So it will reduce some code.

Answer (score 5):

If you using [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/) nuget package, there is a way keep log4net config in appsettings.json (but honestly not very usable).

You can write into appsettings.json (or appsettings.Environment.json for different environments) rules overriding nodes from log4net config file.

[Documentation](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/blob/develop/doc/CONFIG.md)

Example of setting the logging level from appsettings.json.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Log4NetCore": {
    "PropertyOverrides": [
      {
        "XPath": "/log4net/root/level",
        "Attributes": {
          //"value": "ALL"
          //"value": "DEBUG"
          //"value": "INFO"
          "value": "WARN"
          //"value": "ERROR"
          //"value": "FATAL"
          //"value": "OFF"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You still needs log4net config file with nodes which you want override from appsettings.json:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="example.log" />
     <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Registration in Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // Add these lines
        var loggingOptions = this.Configuration.GetSection("Log4NetCore")
                                               .Get<Log4NetProviderOptions>();
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net(loggingOptions);

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this?